# how we can read xml files other than xmlTeaxtReader and xmlReader

Tags: c#-3.0

how we can read xml files other than xmlTextReader and xmlReader

Comment: Why don't you want to use those classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always [load the XML into dataset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx29c3yd(VS.71).aspx) which might be easier for some people. Also checkout [System.Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.aspx) namespace and also [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)